# How to change static ip to dynamic ip in web application using golang?

Tags: go

I googled it but they are showing to change the ip of system. But I need to change for my particular web application as I have a config file in that I have tagged with ip port number as shown DB_info type ="postgres" **ip="10.11.0.17"** port="5432" but for every time I need to change the ip for other system.

So I need to make it as dynamic ip instead of static ip in golang.

Comment: You asked this question once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084208/how-to-change-static-ip-to-dynamic-ip-in-golang

Comment: ya but  i dnt got the answer for that

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. If you're looking for a dynamic endpoint management system, look at consul https://www.consul.io/

Comment: c i have a dynamic config file there i am specifying db type,ip,port as shown below

Comment: <DB_info type ="postgres" ip="10.11.0.17" port="5432" so instead of hard coding the ip value i need to take it dynamically

Comment: @jeeva really look at consul, it has its own DNS service that will allow you to just write something like `ip="mydb.mydomain"`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are really need but my telepathy skill says me that you just want to know how to load DB configuration from file. If I'm right there is solution.

Your `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <DB_info type ="postgres" ip="10.11.0.17" port="5432" />
</config>
```

Code for this `config.xml`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type Configuration struct {
    DBInfo  struct {
        Type string `xml:"type,attr"`
        IP   string `xml:"ip,attr"`
        Port int    `xml:"port,attr"`
    } `xml:"DB_info"`
}

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("config.xml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    config := Configuration{}
    err = xml.NewDecoder(file).Decode(&config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(config.DBInfo.IP)
}
```

You can use `config.DBInfo` elements as you wish - init DB, display to user, etc. More about XML parsing in Go [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/).